# How can I have a virtual host for development and another for production with Phusion Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Basically I would like to access the same Rails app in production or environment mode depending on the URL. Is this possible? How?

I tried setting up two different virtual hosts, with different urls and values for RailsEnv, but that doesnt work: Apache will only serve one of the two environments for either urls, more specifically the first that was requested since Apache was started.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The development server is meant for trying code you just wrote. You really want the production server with the same codebase? It looks like a XY problem http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341 :)

Comment: Heh, I like that XY concept. I know this is not a very useful thing to do, but we dont have a production server for this app yet and wanted to give access to our client to the dev server, but preferably in the production environment for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a 10,000ft view, I'm guessing Passenger keeps track of apps internally by their full filesystem paths. So to Passenger, your two instances look like the same one.

You might try pointing your development vhost at a symlink instead - that may trick Passenger. If not, couldn't you just use two different checkouts of your code? That would definitely work.

Comment: That makes sense, I am going to try that